# How do I know if Amazon Elastic Transcoder has completed transcoding

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to have Amazon Elastic Transcoder inform a call back script that it has finished transcoding a specific video conversion?

I'm working on this project that will let people upload videos, it has different steps and each step should start at successful completion of the previous step.

I have been able to trigger the next step in every step but the last step is actually calling the AET and instructing it to go and take some videos from a S3 bucket, transcode them and store them in a different S3 bucket.

So now I need to know if the AET has finished its task or not, I don't like regularly checking for the status with some kind of cron job, I much rather have the AET inform the system that it has finished its task.

Comment: "Amazon Elastic Transcoder does support notifications through Amazon SNS" from https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=429527

Comment: I've used this method successfully. You can then either publish to a URL or subscribe an SQS to the SNS Topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elastic Transcoder uses Amazon SNS (simple notification service) to notify you of status changes. You can set up the SNS topic when you create the pipeline:

http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/faqs/#How_do_I_use_notifications